# Custom typings for external module (with classes) not recognized

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules, typescript-typings

I am having trouble generating the correct syntax for a Typescript types file for an external CommonJS module which uses provides multiple classes.  The NPM module `socket.io-mock` does not provide any Typescript typings to pull from so I decided to define my own as I went.  The overall goal is simulating the socketio connections for testing my React App which is exclusively in Typescript.  I dug through the repository code and determined all the typings necessary.  This is my types file I came up with:

```
// FILE: socketio-mock.d.ts

// Import implementation
import "socket.io-mock"

declare module "socket.io-mock" {
  export = SocketMock
  export = SocketClient

  declare class Emitter {
    constructor(obj?: Partial<Emitter>): Emitter
    _callbacks: { [event: string]: Function[] }
    on: (event: string, callback: (payload?: unknown) => void) => Emitter
    off: (event?: string, fn?: Function) => Emitter
    // ...
  }
  declare class SocketClient extends Emitter {
    constructor(socketMock: SocketMock): SocketClient
    connected: boolean
    disconnected: boolean
    emit: (eventKey: string, payload?: unknown, ack?: () => void) => void
    disconnect: () => SocketClient
    // ...
  }
  declare class SocketMock extends Emitter {
    constructor(): SocketMock
    joinedRooms: string[]
    emit: (eventKey: string, payload?: unknown) => void
    // ...
  }
  export default SocketMock
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  How do I get vscode and more importantly the compiler to recognize the types defined and also not fail when I call?

If I don't use declare in the types file and instead just use `export class`.  It at least compiles but then I get a error code on the new keyword when I run my test suite.  This may be a **red herring** since based on the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html) I should be using declare as above

```
// FILE: App.test.tsx
import { SocketMock, SocketClient } from "socket.io-mock"

describe("<App />", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const fakeServerSocket: SocketMock = new SocketMock()
    //                                   ^
    // TypeError: _socket2.SocketMock is not a constructor
    // ...
  })
  it("renders correctly", async () => {
    // ...
  })
})
```

It is important that I am able to export both the SocketMock & SocketClient classes.

Comment: Where is `_socket2` coming from?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know.  That is the output in from `npm run env -- react-scripts test` which runs my App.test.tsx file.  The bottom snippet is from the beforeEach() hook

Comment: Where did you put `socketio-mock.d.ts`?

Comment: It is placed in the `src/typescripts-declarations/` folder.  My `tsconfig.ts` is configured to include "src".